# How do i clean up this nested Rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this

```
devise_for :users
 resources :sites do
  resources :users
  get 'companies/search'
 end
 root :to => "welcome#index"
end
```

and the routes look like this

```
       site_users GET    /sites/:site_id/users(.:format)            users#index
                  POST   /sites/:site_id/users(.:format)            users#create
    new_site_user GET    /sites/:site_id/users/new(.:format)        users#new
   edit_site_user GET    /sites/:site_id/users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
        site_user GET    /sites/:site_id/users/:id(.:format)        users#show
                  PUT    /sites/:site_id/users/:id(.:format)        users#update
                  DELETE /sites/:site_id/users/:id(.:format)        users#destroy
 site_companies_search GET /sites/:site_id/companies/search(.:format)  sites/:site_id/companies#search
            sites GET    /sites(.:format)                           sites#index
                  POST   /sites(.:format)                           sites#create
         new_site GET    /sites/new(.:format)                       sites#new
        edit_site GET    /sites/:id/edit(.:format)                  sites#edit
             site GET    /sites/:id(.:format)                       sites#show
                  PUT    /sites/:id(.:format)                       sites#update
                  DELETE /sites/:id(.:format)                       sites#destroy
             root        /                                          welcome#index
```

But i want to know if there is a way to have the routes like this

```
       site_users GET    /:site_id/users(.:format)            users#index
                  POST   /:site_id/users(.:format)            users#create
    new_site_user GET    /:site_id/users/new(.:format)        users#new
   edit_site_user GET    /:site_id/users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
        site_user GET    /:site_id/users/:id(.:format)        users#show
                  PUT    /:site_id/users/:id(.:format)        users#update
                  DELETE /:site_id/users/:id(.:format)        users#destroy
```

Without the /sites in the url so the url goes from

```
/sites/some_name/users 
/sites/some_name/users/new
```

to

```
/some_name/users 
/some_name/users/new
```

that will clean up the url if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resources :sites do
  get 'companies/search'
end
scope ':site_id' do
  resources :users
end
root :to => "welcome#index"
```

Comment: would this work the same way as /sites/1/users or is there a different behavior

Comment: also can i use a name instead of an id...so maybe a friendly_id

Comment: Yes a constant name would work.  This is the new way to do Rails App prefixes.  I knew scope could be used with a constant string, and only discovered that it would work with an :id from looking it up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to use this in addition to resource-loading mechanisms like inherited_resources and have your `site` CRUD actions at `/`, you can draw your routes like:

```
resources :sites, :path => "" do
  get 'companies/search'

  resources :users
end

root :to => "welcome#index"
```